# Can not add a new reference from an new project in my solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I did this thousand time but now it doesn't work. 
I added a new project to my current solution. then I added a reference from the new project to the existing one. but I always get the error when I trying to build:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'AccessClass' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried different things, cleanup the solution, rebuild, etc. without success.
the solution is under source control (TFS). but this should not be a problem, isn't it??

any suggestions to solve this issue?

thanks,
tro

Comment: are the .NET versions the same between the two?

Comment: Is AccessClass inside a namespace?  At the very least, you should need a:
  using MyProjectName;
at the top of your code file where you're attempting to use it... or potentially a:
  using MyNameSpace.MyProjectName;

Answer (score 0):

check on the configuration manager of the solution in vs2012. It might not be building your new project in which case there is no dll or exe to reference.